# How to reset a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, reset

I have a gridview which takes inputs from a textbox. Multiple values can be added to it. I want to rest the grid. I have tried few codes in the internet. But just clear the grid. When i type the numbers again all the previous numbers appear. I want to remove previous numbers too when i reset the grid. How can i do it?

Here is my back end code

```
if (grdPolicyDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
{
            grdPolicyDetails.Columns.Clear();
            grdPolicyDetails.DataBind();
}
```

I  have tried this code too. This too didn't work.

```
        grdPolicyDetails.DataSource = null;
        grdPolicyDetails.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the History of Browser ? if yes then,

If Clear Gridview Data then,

```
grdpolicydetails.Controls.Clear();
```

Comment: I want to remove data in the gridview not the textbox

Comment: Can you be more precise about your question.What does it means 'When i type the numbers again all the previous numbers appear'. are you using ochange event how it is automatically getting fetched,are you storing the data in Session variable ?

Comment: as you mentioned I have taken it to session. Thats what created the problem. Thanks

Comment: autocomplete="off" within the asp tag is not necessary to perform the task